# UV map appears on blender, but saves as a blank image

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

i was coming back to a project i've abandoned for quite a while, i'm trying to learn about UV maps and making my own textures, but for some reason, with this project in particular, there's something weird happening

When UV Unwrapping the object (Using the smart UV option if that helps), the map appears normally on blender, but when saving the image, it's just a blank, transparent photo
[image: A flower in blender, selected, it's map appearing in the right side of the screen]

Here's how it looks on blender, but when i save it and put it into GIMP

[image: A blank png image on gimp]

This never happened to me before, in fact, i remember it working perfectly in a previous attempt, i don't know what am i doing wrong

Comment: Can you explain the process that you followed to save the UV grid?, my guess is that you did not select the grid during the saving operation.

Comment: I unwraped the object with the optioned mentioned above, and with it selected, i opened the UV Editing tab and saved it, it looked like the first picture posted

Comment: maybe what you want is to save the UV layout (and not the image, which is transparent)? In that case in the UV Editor > header menu > UV > Export UV Layout

Comment: That was it!, thank you so so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to save the UV layout, not the image, which is transparent. To save the UV layout, go into the *UV Editor* > header menu > *UV > Export UV Layout*.